# I can't render my component dynamically in react using the map function

Tags: reactjs, arrays, dictionary, components

I'm currently learning react but for a reason I don't understand what I am doing wrong , I am trying to generate components dynamically using the map function on a array to render the components . here's my code , I didn't find what I was looking for on the internet , thanks for your help . here's the errors that my console is returning me :

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

I also followed a bunch of tutorials and they all seems to be doing exactly like this also when I try to render the components using only the props of the objects of the array and putting it into a native dom element it is perfectly working .

```
import React from "react";
import "./index.css"
import  ReactDOM  from "react-dom/client";


function App() {
  
  const array  = [

        {
            setup:"c'est un setup",
            punchline:"c'est une punchline"
        },
        {
            setup:"c'est un setup",
            punchline:"c'est une punchline"
        },
        {
            setup:"c'est un setup",
            punchline:"c'est une punchline"
        },
        {
            setup:"c'est un setup",
            punchline:"c'est une punchline"
    
        },
       
    ]

const joke = array.map( Joke =>{

    
    return(
        
        <Joke setup={Joke.setup} punchline={Joke.punchline}/>
        
        )
        
    }
    
    )
    
    console.log(array);




return(
 
    
    
    <div>

    {joke}

    </div>

    
)















}


let root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root"));
root.render(<App/>);
```

Comment: Joke is an object. You can not render object as react element. You can not use object like this: <Joke>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

export default App = () => {
  const array = [
    {
      setup: "c'est un setup",
      punchline: "c'est une punchline"
    },
    {
      setup: "c'est un setup",
      punchline: "c'est une punchline"
    },
    {
      setup: "c'est un setup",
      punchline: "c'est une punchline"
    },
    {
      setup: "c'est un setup",
      punchline: "c'est une punchline"
    }
  ];

  // This is possible
  // const jokes = array.map((joke) => {
  //   return <Joke setup={joke.setup} punchline={joke.punchline} />;
  // });

  // This is cleaner
  return (
    <div>
      {array.map((joke) => {
        return <Joke {...joke} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

This should do the job.

Comment: I tried what you sent but it says to me that Joke is not defined

Comment: @williamjaulin I figured you had a custom component for that. When something starts with a capital letter (<Joke />), it's expected to be a component. You could change `<Joke />` part with ```<p>{`Setup: ${joke.setup} | punchline: ${joke.punchline}`}</p>``` if you want to visualize it

Comment: thanks I intended to create a custom component with the map function indeed but it's not working do you know how to do custom custom components using map ? thanks again for your time .

Comment: I'm so stupid sorry I wasted your time , the heat is completely destroying my brain cells , I found the solution thanks again !

Comment: @williamjaulin Haha yeah all good, no problem. Did you fix it?

Comment: Yeah I fixed it just good , I was so dumb I believed I didn't need to create a Component on his own but it was so silly of me , I needed to create the component and then map the data of the array into it , I believed map would just render the component directly , thanks for your time .